# How to use Repository Interface that uses Generics with Dependency Injection?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container, ioc-container

I am attempting to use the following Generic Repository Interface for DI and constructor injection:

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> : IDisposable where TEntity : class
```

The problem is in order to define an instance of the Interface, I must provide the class type like this:

```
private IRepository<Person> _personRepository;
```

The issue with this is if I'm using DI (and I'm using Unity for IoC framework), then I have to define multiple instances in my constructor to get all repository interfaces I need to work with like this:

```
public MyClass(IRepository<Person> personRepository,
               IRepository<Orders> ordersRepository,
               IRepository<Items> itemsRepository,
               IRepository<Locations> locationsRepository)
{
  _personRepository = personRepository;
  _OrdersRepository = ordersRepository; 
  _itemsRepository = itemsRepository;
  _locationsRepository = locationsRepository;
}
```

Questions:

1. Is this OK?
2. If not where am I lost on this concept?
3. Even if this is proper, what's the point of Unity to register Interface to concrete type? I've already done it because the generic repository forced me on declaration.

Please help clear this up for me, and I appreciate all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this OK?

Sure.  There's personal preference on whether to use constructor injection like you have or property injection.  Constructor injection is cleaner since you don't have to have  lot of parameters to your constructor, but it's safer as well.

> what's the point of Unity to register Interface to concrete type

One reason is so that you can unit test `MyClass` without having to use your actual repository that hits a database.  You can "fake" out the repository to return hard-coded values to test against.

Comment: What I wish I could do is have `IRepository<T> repository` as the method parameter, but I know that will not work. Can you explain why it will not? It feels wrong passing all of those in, but maybe it's proper and I'm over-thinking.

Comment: Because each repository is a different type, and MyClass (apparently) needs 4 different repositories.  You have to provide the concrete classes separately.  It's not wrong (or uncommon) to have several dependencies injected the way you do.

Comment: But what with the situation when would I need an additional method?

Answer (score 11):

As noted by D Stanley, a dependency must be a concrete interface.  Otherwise, where are you going to declare T?  Your dependent class could be generic, but you still have to say "T is a Person" at some point.

That said, Unity handles registering generic types pretty nicely.

Let's say you implement `IRepository<T>` with a generic class `Repository<T>` that wraps a `DbSet<T>` (or whatever).

The following registration and resolves will then work (which includes injecting into any constructors):

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));

// no specific registration needed for the specific type resolves
container.Resolve(<IRepository<Person>);
container.Resolve(<IRepository<Order>);
```

If you needed a specific override of a type (says the Items repository is special for whatever reason so it has a fully implemented `ItemRepository` class), just register that specific implementation after the generic one:

```
container.RegisterType<IRepository<Item>, ItemRepository>();
```

Resolving `IRespository<Item>` will now get your specific implementation.

For the record, I think this can only be done in code, and not configuration files.  Someone feel free to correct that assumption.

Comment: You can register the generic classes in Unity configuration files.  I have done it.  `<register type="IRepository[[Item]]" mapTo="ItemRepository" />` is an example.  Love me some Unity.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using an [Aggregate Service](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/AggregateService) that bundles several other services together, but you should also look carefully to see if your `MyClass` is [trying to do too much](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle); having a very large number of dependencies can be a indication of that.

Comment: The aggregate service in this special case is call a [Unit of Work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html).

Answer (score 2):

This seems ok except one missing point; you need UnitOfWork pattern to enable transactions.
Without UnitOfWork pattern applied, all repositories try to commit db operations on different contexts.

Comment: Nothing in his question points toward him requiring UoW. As someone else pointed out, maybe his class is doing too much, but he never stated anything about trying to commit modifications on all repository at once. Also, technically, different repositories don't necessarily use different context.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do this using configuration file. It's actually pretty easy but took me a while to figure it out.

In this example we have an interface `IRepository<T>` and it has 2 implementations:

1. `OneRepository`
2. `TwoRepository`

We then have a class named `Worker` which depends on `IRepository<One>` and `IRepository<Two>`. We ask unity to create an instance of `Worker` for us and figure out the dependencies from the config file.

**Interface and Implementation**

*All of these are in the namespace `ConsoleApplication1` in this example.*

```
public class Worker
{
    private readonly IRepository<One> one;
    private readonly IRepository<Two> two;

    public Worker(IRepository<One> one, IRepository<Two> two)
    {
        this.one = one;
        this.two = two;
    }

    public string DoOne()
    {
        return this.one.Add(new One());
    }

    public string DoTwo()
    {
        return this.two.Add(new Two());
    }
}

public interface IRepository<T>
{
    string Add(T t);
}

public class OneRepository : IRepository<One>
{
    public string Add(One t)
    {
        return "One";
    }
}

public class TwoRepository : IRepository<Two>
{
    public string Add(Two t)
    {
        return "Two";
    }
}

public class One { }
public class Two { }
```

**Unity Configuration**

Please note we instruct unity and tell it the name of the assembly. Then we register the 2 implementations.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration" />
  </configSections>
  <unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
    <assembly name="ConsoleApplication1" />
    <container>
      <register type="ConsoleApplication1.IRepository[[ConsoleApplication1.One]]" mapTo="ConsoleApplication1.OneRepository" />
      <register type="ConsoleApplication1.IRepository[[ConsoleApplication1.Two]]" mapTo="ConsoleApplication1.TwoRepository" />
    </container>
  </unity>
</configuration>
```

**Application**

This is the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
        var res = container.LoadConfiguration();
        Worker worker = res.Resolve<Worker>();
        Console.WriteLine(worker.DoOne());
        Console.WriteLine(worker.DoTwo());
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

The output as expected is:

```
One
Two
```